# Why is the title of a question a hyperlink?

Tags: discussion

The title of this question is a hyperlink that leads you back to the question itself.

Not that this is a big bug but it is a usability issue.

I see no use of the hyperlink. On the other hand it causes nuisance when I'm trying to select text from the title for a google search.

Comment: My guess is that it's a standard shared control that is used to display the question title, not only from within a question, but on the search pages and other areas of the system too, hence the link is there.

Comment: @Tanner Okay it might be a technical limitation. But from UX design perspective should it be so?

Comment: The same reason why a website's brand/logo is usually a hyperlink to the index of the site. To give the user access to the "default" version of the page.

Comment: It's probably also a leftover from back when there didn't use to be a "share" link - the question title was the only permalink back to the question.

Comment: @remyabel "default" version? Is there another version I'm missing?

Comment: @Kshitiz Sharma: It is possible to link to a specific answer to the question. You can change it into a link to the question by simply removing the answer id at the end (after the question slug), but that would involve manipulating the URL.

Comment: maybe because it's natural that you click the thing that interests you. besides questions are not articles that have summary or blurb.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is probably not *the* answer but I can see why it's useful for a couple of reasons.

- If you want instant access to the permalink, you don't have to go down to the tiny share button and then copy the link. You can hover your mouse over the gigantic question title, which you're instantly greeted with, and copy the link from there.
- If you've clicked on a [comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/287022/why-is-the-title-of-a-question-a-hyperlink/287027#comment160110_287022) or [answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/287027/839601)'s permalink, and then you scroll and refresh the page, you will be instantly annoyed when your screen is now centered on that answer or comment. Clicking on the question title is an easy way to "reset" the URL without having to mess with the URL in the location bar.

I'm also not sure how you're having trouble selecting the text without clicking on it. There's plenty of whitespace around for you to start the selection from.

Comment: `There's plenty of whitespace around` Doesn't help if I want to select part of it.

Comment: @Kshitiz, don't know which browser you use, but in Firefox you can hold `Alt` while selecting in order to force text selection, even on links.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi Tried on `FF35` Linux. Doesn't work.

Comment: @Kshitiz, ah, I can only test on FF 35 Windows right now. Maybe it's a Windows-only thing...

Comment: On a Mac Chrome, it's the 'shift' key. I'm not saying it's going to be the same key for Firefox or for Firefox on Linux, but it's probably one of those modifier keys: shift, alt, ctrl, or function. That being said, I understand the issue, it's a very minor issue for me. Personally, I usually copy the beginning of a title, or the end of a title, I've never tried copying the middle words inside a title, but I can now see why it's a minor annoyance to you.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi you are a wonderful human being for that firefox tip